# Kendo Mobile - MVVM Need help binding view model with datasource

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is wrong here. i am trying to bind a view to a view model, and then bind a datasource array within the view, from the view model. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
        <div id="mDashboardView" data-role="view" data-bind="homeScreenModel" data-init="initDefaultView">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div>
                    <div class="m-parent-navigation-container">
                        <section data-bind="source: data" data-template="mDashboardViewTemplate">
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
           var homeScreenModel = kendo.observable({
                data: new Array(),
                navigationCategories: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "api/GetNavigationData",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "d.results",
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                nameOfGroup: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    change: function (e) {
                        homeScreenModel.trigger("change", { field: "navigationCategories" });
                    }
                })
            });

function initDefaultView(event) {
    homeScreenModel.navigationCategories.read();
}
</script>
```

I keep getting one templated item that's undefined, but my datasource has 4 items in it, as my scheme-model shows. Also, I get this warning twice:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
(anonymous function)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using Kendo UI Mobile v2013.1.319 and JQuery 1.9.1

Comment: Could you post in JSFiddle / JSBin the code showing the problem so we can troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function to use:
homeScreenModel.navicationCategories.fetch();